# grub entry for system uefi device list

Tags: linux, boot, grub, uefi

I seem to remember that GRUB makes possible a menu entry that launches the system boot-device menu. This behavior is convenient for users who may wish to boot from removable media, but prefer invoking  the system device list from the GRUB menu, which appears unconditionally under many configurations, rather than   by a keystroke pressed at the appropriate time during system boot.

Is this behavior supported, or have I only imagined it?

Comment: It has an entry to go into UEFI, but not the UEFI boot menu. If you know which drive it is, you can create a chain load entry in grub. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/bootUSB

Comment: @oldfred: The idea is that if you have a removable, bootable device, you could insert the device, boot the system, and then when the Grub menu loads, you could select a menu option that showed the list generated by the firmware of all bootable media. This list would be same  one as  invoked by the appropriate key press before the OS bootloader begins, but without the hassle of timing the key press precisely inside of a narrow time interval.

Comment: Take a look at rEFInd. I think it can use the entries you see with efibootmgr or do its own scan of system to find bootable systems. I do use rEFInd as emergency boot and it does work. I installed it to an old flash drive that now is too small for much else. Alternative efi boot manager for UEFI limited systems:
http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/ &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/908677/want-to-view-contents-of-boot-efi-in-xubuntu-dont-have-permissions

Comment: @oldfred: rEFind looks like a nice project. I think that the demands for configuration and maintenance are greater than I care to adopt. I was looking for something rather lightweight. I suppose pressing F9 during the time window might be my best option.